# Prove that real parts of eigenvalues of Complex Matrix are positive.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm doing a Numerical Analysis Course in the which we have the following exercise which I've been struggling to crack.

I've attempted going through the classical caracteristic polynomial approach but it's an algebraic nightmare.

The exercice is :

Given the following matrix,

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 5 + i & -3/2  & 0 & 3i/2 \\ 1/2 & 6 & i & i/2 \\
\sqrt2 & \sqrt2i & 4+3i & 0 \\ i & 1 & i & 2+4i \end{pmatrix}$

Show that all eignenvalues of A have a positive or null real part.

You may use the following diagram to explain this :

[Exercise Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxAjp.png)

Many Thanks !

Comment: The two figures suggest that Gerschgorin disc theorem may be useful here.